# How to pass jquery object and opts on fancybox.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

Hello everyone so i've ran into a problem. I've got a jquery object:
`const popup = $('#popup')` and I pass it to fancybox
`$.fancybox.open(popup);` but I also want to run an
`afterClose` on this popup, didn't manage to find any info on how to do this. Did anyone run in this problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src  : '#popup',
    type : 'inline',
    opts : {
      afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
        console.info('done!');
      }
    }
  });
```